# Print Layout For A4 Size Paper

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

We want to print out badges on a A4 paper. The names and pictures of participants
will be pulled out from a web database to print on an already formatted A4 paper
with fixed placeholders for the names and pictures.

The A4 layout is made upof 5 rows and 2 columns, each cell containing the badge info.

The question is how do I specify the measurements in css style sheet so that the output
prints exactly to the placeholders. Just some general tips on how to handle this - unit
of measurement, box model, distance from outer container.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, but I'll bite. You can use physical units like `mm` and `cm` in your CSS. I would look into the new CSS flexbox and grid for positioning so you don't have to worry about float drops and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute lengths.

> in: inches — 1in is equal to 2.54cm.
>
> cm: centimeters
>
> mm: millimeters

Ex:

```
.wrap {
  width: 20cm; 
}
```

more [info](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) about absolute lengths.

> 1em == 16px == 0.17in == 12pt == 1pc == 4.2mm == 0.42cm